# Are the Sierpiński cardinal $\acute{\mathfrak n}$ and its measure modification $\acute{\mathfrak m}$ equal to some known small uncountable cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, cardinal-characteristics

This question was motivated by an answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285777/anti-fixed-point-property/285779#285779) of Dominic van der Zypen.

It relates to the following classical theorem of Sierpiński.

**Theorem (Sierpiński, 1921).** For any countable partition of the unit interval $[0,1]$ into closed subsets exactly one set of the partition is non-empty.

Motivated by this Sierpiński Theorem we can ask about the smallest infinite cardinality $\acute{\mathfrak n}$ of a partition of the unit interval into closed non-empty subsets. It is clear that $\acute{\mathfrak n}\le\mathfrak c$. The Sierpinski Theorem guarantees that $\omega_1\le\acute{\mathfrak n}$. So, $\acute{\mathfrak n}$ is a typical small uncountable cardinal living in the segment $[\omega_1,\mathfrak c]$.

**Problem 1.** Is $\acute{\mathfrak n}$ equal to some other known small uncountable cardinal?

**Problem 2.** Is $\acute{\mathfrak n}$ equal to $\mathfrak c$ under Martin's Axiom?

---

We can also can consider the measure modification of the cardinal $\acute{\mathfrak n}$.

Namely, let $\acute{\mathfrak m}$ be the smallest cardinality of a cover of $[0,1]$ by pairwise disjoint closed subsets of Lebesgue measure zero.

The definitions imply that $\acute{\mathfrak n}\cdot\mathrm{cov}({\mathcal N})\le\acute{\mathfrak m}\le\mathfrak c$.

According to Theorem 4 of [Miller](http://www.math.wisc.edu/%7Emiller/res/cov.pdf), the strict inequality $\acute{\mathfrak m}<\mathfrak c$ is consistent. So, $\acute{\mathfrak m}$ is a non-trivial small uncountable cardinal.

**Problem 3.** Is it consistent that $\acute{\mathfrak n}<\acute{\mathfrak m}$?

**Problem 4.** Is $\acute{\mathfrak m}$ equal to some known small uncountable cardinal?

---

**Added after analyzing comments to these problems:** As was observed by @Ashutosh, the answer to Problem 2 is affirmative. In [his paper](http://www.math.wisc.edu/%7Emiller/res/cov.pdf) Miller writes that this was done by Both (1968, unpublished) and Weiss (1972, unpublished). The MA equality $\acute{\mathfrak n}=\mathfrak c$ can be also derived from the ZFC inequality $$\mathfrak d\le\acute{\mathfrak n},$$ which can be proved as follows: given a partition $\mathcal P$ of $[0,1]$ into pairwise disjoint closed sets with $|\mathcal P|=\acute{\mathfrak n}$, we can choose a countable subfamily $\mathcal P'\subset\mathcal P$ such that the space $X=[0,1]\setminus\bigcup\mathcal P'$ is nowhere locally compact and hence is homeomorphic to $\omega^\omega$. Then $\mathcal P\setminus\mathcal P'$ is a cover of $X\cong\omega^\omega$ by compact subsets, which implies that $\acute{\mathfrak n}=|\mathcal P\setminus\mathcal P|'\ge\mathfrak d$ by the definition of the cardinal $\mathfrak d$.

[Miller](http://www.math.wisc.edu/%7Emiller/res/cov.pdf) proved the consistency of the strict inequality $\acute{n}<\mathfrak c$. Looking at the diagram of small uncountable cardinals in [Vaughan](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9065/61a1e45b49a2ab816e088ffd33279c05a3ba.pdf), I found only three small uncountable cardinals above $\mathfrak d$: $\mathfrak i$, $cof(\mathcal M)$ and $cof(\mathcal L)$.

**Problem 5.** Is $\acute{\mathfrak n}$ equal to one of the cardinals $\mathfrak d$, $\mathfrak i$, $cof(\mathcal M)$ or $cof(\mathcal L)$ in ZFC?

---

**Summing up the progress made sofar.** The cardinals $\acute{\mathfrak n}$ and $\acute{\mathfrak m}$ satisfy the following ZFC-inequalities:

$$\mathfrak d\le \acute{\mathfrak n}\le\acute{\mathfrak m}=\acute{\mathfrak n}\cdot\mathrm{cov}_{\sqcup}(\mathcal N)\le\mathfrak c.$$

Here by $\mathrm{cov}_{\sqcup}(\mathcal N)$ we denote the smallest cardinality of a disjoint cover of $[0,1]$ by Borel Lebesgue null sets.

It is clear  that $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal N)\le\mathrm{cov}_\sqcup(\mathcal N)$ and $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal N)=\aleph_1$ implies $\mathrm{cov}_\sqcup(\mathcal N)=\aleph_1$.

So, $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal N)=\aleph_1$ implies the equality $\acute{\mathfrak n}=\acute{\mathfrak m}$.

Below I collect two consistency results observed by

**Will Brian**: $\acute{\mathfrak m}<\mathrm{non}(\mathcal N)$ is consistent;

**Ashutosh**: $\acute{\mathfrak n}=\aleph_1$ in the random real model (in this model $\acute{\mathfrak m}=\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal N)=\mathrm{non}(\mathcal M)=\mathfrak i=\mathfrak r=\mathfrak c$), so $\acute{\mathfrak n}<\acute{\mathfrak m}$ is consistent.

The above results suggest the following questions:

**Problem 6.** Is $\mathfrak d<\acute{\mathfrak n}$ consistent?

**Problem 7.** Is $\acute{\mathfrak n}$ upper bounded by some known small uncountable cardinal different from $\mathfrak c$? For example, is $\acute{\mathfrak n}\le \mathrm{cof}(\mathcal N)$ true in ZFC?

**Problem 8.** Is $\acute{\mathfrak m}=\acute{\mathfrak n}\cdot\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal N)$?

**Problem 9.** Is $\mathrm{cov}_\sqcup(\mathcal N)=\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal N)$?

Comment: The answer to 2. is yes. See the last paragraph in http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/cov.pdf 

This is also theorem 3 here: Stern J. (1978) Partitions of the real line into $\aleph_1$ closed sets. In: Müller G.H., Scott D.S. (eds) Higher Set Theory. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, vol 669. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg

Comment: @Goldstern Thank you! I have corrected this inequality.

Comment: @Ashotosh Thank you for the link to Miller's paper. Reading this paper I have understood that the inequalities $\acute{\mathbb n}\le cov(\mathcal M)$ and $\acute{\mathfrak n}=\mathfrak c$ are not true in ZFC.  Right? What actually is proved in Theorem 5 of Miller? That $cov(\mathcal N)\le\acute{\mathfrak n}$ or $\mathfrak p\le\acute{\mathfrak n}$?

Comment: Theorem 5 says that $\acute{\mathfrak n} = \aleph_1$ in the random real model. In particular $cov(Null) > \acute{\mathfrak n}$ is consistent. I don't know if $\mathfrak{p} \leq \acute{\mathfrak n}$. You should check the proof of MA implies $\acute{\mathfrak n} = \mathfrak{c}$ in Stern's paper - I cannot access it. Maybe the forcing used is sigma-centered?

Comment: @Ashutosh I am not so fluent in forcing, unfortunately :(

Comment: So, I will wait for the expert's opinion.

Comment: I just looked at the proof of MA implies $\acute{\mathfrak n} = \mathfrak{c}$ in Stern's paper. He uses a countable poset (Cohen forcing) so $ \mathfrak{p} \leq \acute{\mathfrak n}$ does hold.

Comment: My answer at https://mathoverflow.net/q/48991 shows that $\acute{\mathfrak n}\geq\text{cov}(B)$ (where $B$ means Baire category, also known as $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal K$).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you. I also (when went for shopping) realized this inequality $\acute{\mathfrak n}\ge cov(\mathcal M)$. Moreover, the same proof yields a bit more: $\acute{\mathfrak n}\ge\mathfrak d$. The latter inequality can be used to derive the consistency of  $cov(\mathcal M)<\acute{\mathfrak n}$ (proved by A.Miller). Looking at the Cichon diagram it remains to check the retaion of $\acute{\mathfrak n}$ to $cof(\mathcal M)$ and $cof(\mathcal N)$.

Comment: The number $\acute{\mathfrak m}$ is called $cov(\mathcal E)$ in the paper _Closed measure zero sets_ by Bartoszyński and Shelah. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9905123.pdf  Annals Pure and Applied Logic 58 (1992) 93-110, MR1186905.   MR knows of 10 papers referencing this one.

Comment: @Golstern I had in mind that $\acute{\mathfrak m}$ is the smallest cardinality of a **disjoint** cover of $[0,1]$ by closed null sets. I have corrected the definition. Thank you for the comment. The definitions imply that $cov(E)\le\acute{\mathfrak m}$. But $cov(E)\le cov(N)\cdot \mathfrak d$. SInce $\mathfrak d\le\acute{\mathfrak n}\le\acute{\mathfrak m}$, the inequality $cov(E)\le\acute{\mathfrak m}$ is equivalent to $cov(N)\le\acute(\mathfrak m)$. That is why I did not involve the cardinal $cov(\mathcal E)$ in the lover bound $cov(\mathcal N)\cdot \mathfrak d\le\acute{\mathfrak m}$.

Comment: The answer to 3. is yes. In the random real model, $\acute{\mathfrak n} = \aleph_1$ while $\acute{\mathfrak m} \geq cov(Null) = \aleph_2 = \mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: Also, based on @Ashutosh's comment stating that $\acute{\mathfrak{n}} = \aleph_1$ in the random real model, we can conclude that a partial answer to Question 5 is no, $\acute{\mathfrak{n}}$ does not equal $\mathfrak i$, $\mathrm{cof}(\mathcal L)$, or $\mathrm{cof}(\mathcal M)$. All three of these cardinals are equal to $\mathfrak c$ in the random real model, so none of them equals $\acute{\mathfrak{n}}$.

Comment: A related recent question: [Uncountable disjoint closed coverings of $[0,1]$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/337836).

Answer (score 7):

A lot of very good observations have already been put into the comments. I'll add one more observation that's too long for a comment:

> It is consistent that $\acute{\mathfrak{m}} < \mathrm{non}(\mathcal L)$.

The basic idea is to start with a model of MA + $\neg$CH (where $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal L)$ is already big), and then to force over this model to make $\acute{\mathfrak{m}}$ smaller while leaving $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal L)$ large. The proof uses two facts:

*Fact 1:* There is a $\sigma$-centered notion of forcing $P$ that does not change the value of $\mathfrak{c}$ and that forces $\acute{\mathfrak{m}} = \aleph_1$.

*Fact 2:* Suppose $V$ is a model of MA, and $P$ is a $\sigma$-centered notion of forcing (in $V$). Then $P$ does not lower the value of $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal L)$. In particular, if $V \not\models$ CH and if $P$ does not change the value of $\mathfrak{c}$, then $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal L) = \mathfrak{c} > \aleph_1$ in the extension.

My claim follows easily from these two facts. To get a model of $\acute{\mathfrak{m}} < \mathrm{non}(\mathcal L)$, begin with a model of MA + $\mathfrak{c} > \aleph_1$ and force with the notion of forcing $P$ described in Fact 1. The resulting model has $\acute{\mathfrak{m}} = \aleph_1$ (because $P$ makes this true) and $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal L) = \mathfrak{c} > \aleph_1$ (by the "in particular" part of Fact 2). *QED*

Fact 2 is possibly "well known" but I don't know the standard reference. It was first explained to me by Andreas Blass, who exposits it nicely in the proof of Corollary 49 in [this paper](https://wrbrian.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/rearrangement.pdf).

For Fact 1, the notion of forcing from Theorem 4 in [this paper](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/cov.pdf) of Arnie Miller does the job. This forcing -- let us call it $P$ -- is $\sigma$-centered and does not change the value of $\mathfrak c$.$^{(*)}$ $P$ is designed to add a partition of $2^\omega$ into $\aleph_1$ closed sets, and it is easy to show (using a genericity argument) that each set in this partition has measure $0$; Miller even points this out in a comment after the proof of his Theorem 4.

There may be a small issue here about partitioning $2^\omega$ instead of $[0,1]$, but we can get around it. Given our partition of $2^\omega$ into $\aleph_1$ closed measure-zero sets, first observe that none of them has interior in $2^\omega$ (because then it would fail to have measure $0$). Thus there is a countable, dense $D \subset 2^\omega$ that contains no more than one point of any member of our partition. Recall that if $C$ is a closed measure-zero subset of $2^\omega$, then $C$ minus one point is homeomorphic to a countable disjoint union of Cantor sets, so it can be partitioned into countably many closed measure-zero sets. Thus, we may modify our partition by adding in the sets of the form $\{d\}$ with $d \in D$, and then dividing some other sets into countably many pieces. In this way we obtain a partition of $2^\omega$ into $\aleph_1$ closed measure-zero sets, including all sets of the form $\{d\}$ for $d \in D$. Once we have done this, we observe that there is a measure-preserving homeomorphism from $2^\omega \setminus D$ onto $[0,1] \setminus \mathbb Q$. When we push our partition through this homeomorphism, we obtain a partition of $[0,1]$ into $\aleph_1$ closed measure-zero sets.

$(*)$ Neither of these facts is stated explicitly in the linked paper, but neither is difficult to prove either. (Using Miller's notation from the linked paper:) Each forcing of the form $P(X)$ is $\sigma$-centered, because if two conditions agree on the part that asserts sentences of the form "$[s] \cap C_n = \emptyset$'' then they are compatible (take the union of the other part). It is clear that no $P(X)$ increases $\mathfrak c$, because it is too small ($|P(X)| \leq \mathfrak c$ and it has the c.c.c., so there are only $\mathfrak c$ nice names for reals). Thus $P$, which is a length-$\omega_1$, finite support iteration of forcings of the form $P(X)$, also is $\sigma$-centered and does not increase $\mathfrak c$.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. Maybe it yields more, namely, that $\acute{\mathfrak m}<non(\mathcal L)$ is consistent? By the way, writing about the Baire space, maybe you had in mind $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$ (not $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$)? Usually $\mathbb Q$ denotes the set of rational numbers.

Comment: Oops! Yes, I did mean $[0,1] \setminus \mathbb Q$, and I fixed the typo now.

Comment: As for $\acute{\mathfrak{m}}$, it would follow from this argument that $\acute{\mathfrak{m}} < \mathrm{non}(\mathcal L)$ if you could show that the forcing $P$ mentioned in my answer (or some other $\sigma$-centered forcing) adds an $\aleph_1$-sized partition of $[0,1]$ into closed measure-zero sets. I did consider this, but don't know whether it's true. The partition it adds for $2^\omega$ is a partition into closed measure-zero sets, but it's not obvious (to me, anyway) how to get from there to a partition on $[0,1]$. I will think about it some more, though.

Comment: @TarasBanakh: OK, I think I can see how to get $\acute{\mathfrak{m}} < \mathrm{non}(\mathcal L)$ now. I have to go teach now, but will edit my answer when I have the time (tomorrow at the latest).

Comment: The difference between $[0,1]$ and $2^\omega$ is inessential: just observe that for any two dense null $F_\sigma$-sets $A\subset[0,1]$ and $B\subset 2^\omega$ the complements $[0,1]\setminus A$ and $2^\omega\setminus B$ are homeomorphic by a measure-preserving homeomorphism.

Comment: What happens with other cardinal characteristics in your model of $\acute{\mathfrak m}<non(\mathcal L)$? I am especially interested in $non(\mathcal M)$ and $\mathfrak i$.

Comment: @TarasBanakh: $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal M)$ is $\aleph_1$ in this extension because Cohen reals are added at every stage of the iteration (a set $\{r_\alpha : \alpha \in \omega_1\}$ of reals where $r_\alpha$ is Cohen over $V^{P_\alpha}$ will be non-meager in the extension). I'm not sure about $\mathfrak{i}$, but I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1):

None of the cardinals in Cichoń's diagram is an upper bound for $\acute{\mathfrak{n}}$ (or $\acute{\mathfrak{m}}$). This follows from a theorem of Spinas:

> **Theorem:** there is a proper forcing $P$ with the Sacks property such that forcing with $P$ over a model of $\mathsf{CH}$ makes $\acute{\mathfrak{n}} = \aleph_2 = \mathfrak{c}$. Hence $\mathrm{cof}(\mathcal L) < \acute{\mathfrak{n}},\acute{\mathfrak{m}}$ is consistent.

Of course, $\mathrm{cof}(\mathcal L) = \aleph_1$ in the extension implies that all the cardinals in Cichoń's diagram are $\aleph_1$ in the extension.

It has already been pointed out that $\mathfrak{d} \leq \acute{\mathfrak{n}}$, that $\acute{\mathfrak{n}} < \mathrm{non}(\mathcal L)$ is consistent, and that $\acute{\mathfrak{n}}$ is $\aleph_1$ in the random model. Putting all these facts together, we see

> $\mathfrak{d} \leq \acute{\mathfrak{n}}$, but if $\kappa$ is any of the cardinals in Cichoń's diagram not bounded above by $\mathfrak{d}$, then $\acute{\mathfrak{n}}$ is independent of $\kappa$, in the sense that both $\kappa < \acute{\mathfrak{n}}$ and $\acute{\mathfrak{n}} < \kappa$ are consistent.

Spinas proves the above theorem in

> O. Spinas, "Partition numbers,'' *Annals of Pure and Applied Logic* **90** (1997), pp. 243-262. ([link](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271596/1-s2.0-S0168007200X00498/1-s2.0-S0168007297000389/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEE0aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIHqORJuSkesXgfdgRg18Xd%2BG9zO8bMKfn%2FVocLrArxrzAiB%2ByYo4ZHWI7VMqG5xk%2BhaCJ0OkdyFaFUbv6UFpqxiUPSq9AwjF%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAMaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMGOw1u1oa8VaA%2BCRXKpED41tH3Zt06YRYUFYGgXddQg2qlS%2F5tzFI81DCua8tNSY79byUDGNTEJ3sGAAqZHYzX1F2ZpSOYqMyMnQWyHRSxyA1eu4%2FwwHpHjhfUHg4%2BDyq5wFVfGvQskZVKP%2Fv4Y2OPlpaNPs4IsR1meMSDDDnfqeyAuN%2F7mu%2BLOQRReamHBK8ehNGr5SDzx4zfJTo8xgvALDJwMCU1Cu5G9gzeiFoF2nUdwe%2Bvqiu6j%2F8eHVOTMInVybvixrgvYNh3Xu2JPgLr6opGzS%2FMtJvvxVkVdN%2FCfXTDcy2EP0w%2Fm4%2Boxs8Qno5NqJlY%2BcL0Pbm5ZbO6uQbtLI76HjelFQypwBFWURiia1IovaH%2F0KUXztaBOYH%2BNGID2X6e8aOlpVuOBgJ8JpXVl25KP13ru%2BQfCH71DYUFnxswyuIZLtba0kPjbKlBO%2Fn7m0kFMDns7qq2bei1UzuXQ6fAPoWvsvqQBy63Gk9ub16jH2sZ1qA51IERzrFYKYxf6FIlntOl9ST2VhRqNNXq7R99wwkrLZVDqLYWNxsr8Awus6k9wU67AEMPyGtFDucyYOneuFHOPAbCWTfytMFnGeKAPG9RK7rsBszYbUZBSfMvh%2F3WekVbSeUrKkej%2Bedq1ASRu7jJ2lPw6uM%2FQtZsPrzJLK%2F0IGiAav0sCnsoU7zSkJbPDrs1vZgKvsPCKxo6296nrVoerhsV%2Bh7WT6dDKzIfpLmJHb0dLYGQlan4doY1NViqu77NB9HGon1alPLqPfGhhcomyyXOjjjIIX8N6OT%2FaxO3xRLI%2ByudFbqQUp6pc6TRQ61UpX2WinxiUc%2BnG%2F3%2Blv89TIMekxW3hPWmChDF8MHMpalheqh7GgMuF3b8gMZLw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200616T203355Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY46UFOMV3%2F20200616%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=dfece35f6f128ef40c21e32f591c76e1233e63b92049e850860a922dfb317860&hash=c248d5d23b1829eb0b1afb339db572f4a7cbd03b7dcfd3b7e7119ed2bcff8ce5&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0168007297000389&tid=spdf-1b9d71e4-c9b1-4189-8246-e1e6c11a1a9c&sid=52234e8c1865954b76-9115-1dea1c1c3469gxrqa&type=client))

See Theorem 2.8. The notion of forcing $P$ used in Spinas' proof was actually introduced earlier, in [this](http://www.math.wisc.edu/%7Emiller/res/cov.pdf) paper of Arnie Miller (the one Ashutosh links to in the comments). Miller proves that $P$ has the Laver property (in modern terminology -- he doesn't phrase it that way in the paper) and concludes that $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal M) < \acute{\mathfrak{n}}$ is consistent. Spinas shows that $P$ is $\omega^\omega$-bounding which, combined with Miller's result, means it has the Sacks property, which implies $\mathrm{cof}(\mathcal L) < \acute{\mathfrak{n}}$ is consistent. The forcing $P$ is an iteration of tree-like forcings, each of which kills an $\aleph_1$-sized partition in the ground model. The forcing used to kill a partition $\mathcal X$ is the set of all perfect trees $T \subseteq 2^{<\omega}$ having the property that every member of $\mathcal X$ is relatively meager in $[T]$ (the set of branches through $T$).

Finally, let me note that $P$ having the Sacks property does not suffice to conclude that $\mathfrak{i} = \aleph_1$ in the extension. For example, a countable support iteration of Silver forcings has the Sacks property, but $\mathfrak{r} = \mathfrak{i} = \aleph_2$ in the Silver model. (This is proved in Halbeisen's book.) So we cannot conclude that forcing with $P$ makes $\mathfrak{i} = \aleph_1$, and in fact I don't know what is the value of $\mathfrak{i}$ after forcing with $P$. So your question about whether $\mathfrak{i}$ could be an upper bound for $\acute{\mathfrak{n}}$ or $\acute{\mathfrak{m}}$ remains open, although I suspect the answer is negative.

Comment: Thank you for another nice answer!