# Totally non fixed point property

Tags: gn.general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

**Edit:** According to the comment of Pietro  Majer, I revise the question

Is there  a  non singleton compact  connected Hausdorff topological space $X$ for which the following property hold?:

"Constant maps  and the identity are the only maps with fixed point"

Comment: a singleton {*} - for higher dimension, a topological manifold  has a lot of self mappings (e.g. a map only moving points in a small neighborhood of a given point)

Comment: @PietroMajer  I revise the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The paper http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm60/fm60123.pdf contains an example of a compact continuum with the property the only continuous mappings from $X$ to $X$ are the identity mappings and the constant mappings. See also the answer [Strongly rigid Hausdorff spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/q/188729/22277).

However, any compact Hausdorff space $X$ where the only maps $f:X\rightarrow X$ with fixed points are the constant and identity functions must be totally path-disconnected as well as connected: If $X$ is not totally path-disconnected, then there is a path $f:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ with $f(0)\neq f(1)$. However, in this case, there is a homeomorphism $g:C\rightarrow I$ where $C\subseteq X$ is a closed subspace. By Tietze's extension theorem, there is some $h:X\rightarrow I$ that extends $g$, but $g^{-1}\circ h:X\rightarrow X$ is a mapping with $g^{-1}\circ h[X]=C$, so $g^{-1}\circ h$ is not a constant mapping nor the identity mapping, but clearly $g^{-1}\circ h$ is the identity on $C$, so $g^{-1}\circ h $ has plenty of fixed points.

Comment: bof. Yes. That is what I meant to say.

Comment: Sorry, I’m confused. Aren’t all continua compact by definition? Or is this a different notion of a continuum than I think?

Comment: Emil Jarabek. Yes. I was being redundant.

Comment: @JosephVanName thank you for the answer.