# Automorphism-invariant positive linear functionals on $C*$-algebras

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra. Does there exist a non-trivial positive linear functional $\nu\in A^*$ which is $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$-invariant? That is, $\nu\circ\alpha=\nu$ for all $\alpha\in\mathrm{Aut}(A)$. Note that $\nu$ does not have to be bounded.

**Question:** Is there a reference where this question is addressed for wide classes of infinite-dimensional $C^*$-algebras?

I am specifically looking for references. Thank you.

**Discussion:** If $A=M_n$ (matrices of dimension $n\in\mathbb{N}$) then $\nu(a)=\mathrm{tr}[a]$ is one such. If $A$ is commutative then $A\simeq C_0(X)$ for a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, and the question boils down to a Radon measure on $X$ which is $\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$-invariant. If $X$ is discrete then the counting measure does the job. If $X\simeq(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}$ then the answer is no. What happens in between?

Comment: The answers to [Hausdorff spaces with trivial automorphism group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188707/hausdorff-spaces-with-trivial-automorphism-group) give examples in the commutative case, since some of the spaces mentioned there are also compact.

Comment: @TobiasFritz those seem to be spaces with trivial automorphism group, in which case any positive linear functional would do.

Comment: There are $C^\ast$-algebras with unique traces. For example any UHF algebra, or any II$_1$ factor. So traces on such algebras would be examples.

Comment: For an unbounded example, the canonical trace on $B(H)$ for an infinite-dimensional $H$ would work. Or if $M$ is a II$_1$ factor with trivial fundamental group, then any trace on $M \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} B(l^2)$ would do.

Comment: @YemonChoi I did not say that $\nu$ cannot be unbounded. I said quite the contrary: $\nu$ can be unbounded. Such is the case when $A$ is not unital.

Comment: @Bedovlat I made a typo in my previous comment. What I meant to say is: since $\nu$ can be unbounded, what does it mean for it to be Aut($A$)-invariant? Are you requiring the ideal of definition of $\nu$ to be Aut($A$)-invariant? (perhaps this comes for free)

Comment: @YemonChoi All right, if you view $\nu:A^+\to[0,+\infty]$ as a $(0,+\infty)$-linear functional, then its $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$-invariance does yield the invariance of the ideal.